# how to add a new line button to numeric keyboard. TextFormField with phones list

Tags: flutter

I need to make a long TextFormField to insert a lot of phones(for example maxLines:10). Each line is a single phone. Have no idea how to make my keyboard with numbers and break (next line) button only.

TextInputType.number  and TextInputType.phone cannot make a new line.

What to do?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

why don't you display the lines as a list view/column and add a row each time you will enter the next number - so instead of one field with wrapped lines use multiple input fields

Comment: i was thinking about it too, but it will break the design

Comment: You don't necessarily have to see it (polar bear in a snow storm). And you have a clean input of the numbers